# How to deserialize an PHP array with GSON

Tags: java, php, gson

In PHP i serialize an array with json_encode that i try to read on my Android device with GSON. But Android crashes with a fatal exception. I can't get it to work with any of the examples that i've seen. I think it is caused by the JSON string. It starts with the index of the array (19 and 17 in the example below), and i haven't seen any examples of this type of JSON string. All the examples that i have seen start with property names and not with a index / cpunter.

Here's my JSON example:

> {"19":{"id":"1262","username":"abc","telnr":"0123456789","created":"Sun,
>   08 Aug 2010 10:29:06
>   +0200","email":"e@mail.com","code":null},"17":{"id":"1259","username":"cdef","telnr":"9876543210","created":"Sun,
>   08 Aug 2010 10:29:06
>   +0200","email":"mail@domain.com","code":null},

Among many other combinations i tried the following two examples:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType(); 
List<String> personList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

and

```
Type playerType = new TypeToken<List<Player>>(){}.getType(); 
List<Player> players = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), playerType);
```

i get the follow error:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have a Player class / bean that can hold the id, username, telnr, created, email and code properties. I hope somebody can provide me a example of the GSON code that will work on this JSON string. Thanks.

Comment: Did you managed to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The names of properties in a JSON object (the "19" and "17" above) must be valid Javascript identifiers. They can contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs, *but they may not start with a digit.* You must assign different keys or remove the keys altogether to form a Javascript array.

```
$values = array_values($arrayWithKeys);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't know that a JSON string may not start with a digit, but that the problem was in this index became reasonably clear to me. The solution you provided didn't work, it is actually adding an index in front of it {"0":"19","...etc.} I am now looking in another direction to provide the right type of JSON string, without the index. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Add a `var_dump()` of the original array before you convert it to JSON. Given the JSON, I would expect my suggestion to work.